# How to deregister/dequeue jquery.sticky.js in Elementor (Pro)?

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, elementor

I want to increase my page speed by deregistering unnecessary external resources. I already managed to remove most of the external scripts, Elementor loads by default on the frontend. However, I can't remove the jQuery plugin [Sticky](http://stickyjs.com/) somehow. I guess it has to do with being a part of Elementor Pro.

I've already tried to look under jQuery depencies, however that didn't work for me.

```
function remove_jquery_sticky() {
    if ( ! is_admin()) {
        wp_deregister_script( 'sticky' );
    }
}
add_action( 'elementor/frontend/after_register_scripts', 'remove_jquery_sticky' );

I expect the jQuery plugin not to load on the frontend, however it still does.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a solution that works for me. If you've a cleaner solution, please let me know :)

````
    if(is_front_page()) {
        // Dequeue and deregister elementor-sticky
        wp_dequeue_script( 'elementor-sticky' );
        wp_deregister_script( 'elementor-sticky' );

        // Dequeue and deregister elementor-pro-frontend
        wp_dequeue_script( 'elementor-pro-frontend' );
        wp_deregister_script( 'elementor-pro-frontend' );

        // Re-register elementor-frontend without the elementor-sticky dependency.
        $suffix = ( defined( 'SCRIPT_DEBUG' ) && SCRIPT_DEBUG ) ? '' : '.min';
        wp_register_script(
                'elementor-pro-frontend',
                ELEMENTOR_PRO_URL . 'assets/js/frontend' . $suffix . '.js',
                [
                    'elementor-frontend-modules',
                ],
                ELEMENTOR_VERSION,
                true
            );
    }
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'elementor_pro_frontend_scripts' );```
````

Comment: Thanks. It did solve the conflict issue with jquery.sticky.js plugin.

Answer (score 1):

Elementor and Elementor PRO register and enqueue some scripts with dependences. For remove you need deregister and register again without specific script (example without 'elementor-sticky').

```
if(is_front_page()) {

        // Dequeue and deregister elementor-pro-frontend
        wp_deregister_script( 'elementor-pro-frontend' );

        // Re-register elementor-frontend without the elementor-sticky dependency.
        $suffix = ( defined( 'SCRIPT_DEBUG' ) && SCRIPT_DEBUG ) ? '' : '.min';
        wp_register_script(
                'elementor-pro-frontend',
                ELEMENTOR_PRO_URL . 'assets/js/frontend' . $suffix . '.js',
                [
                    'elementor-frontend-modules',
                ],
                ELEMENTOR_VERSION,
                true
            );
    }
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'elementor_pro_frontend_scripts', 20 );
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know the name of the action that is being added you can use the function `remove_action( $tag, $function_to_remove, $priority )` or you can use `wp_dequeue_script( $handle )`

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/remove_action

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_dequeue_script